# Template not calling rendered since upgrading meteor to version 0.9.4

Tags: meteor

Since upgrading to the latest version of meteor my templates `rendered` helper isn't getting called. I read the release docs and they didn't mention any changes concerning the `rendered`. Is anyone having the same issue and if so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Meteor Version > 0.9.3 you have to use `rendered` outside of the `Template.name.helpers`. For example rendered will not be called when using it like this:

```
Template.name.helpers({
   rendered : function () {
      console.log("THIS WONT GET CALLED");
   },
});
```

The correct way to use rendered is outside of the helper construct.

```
Template.name.rendered = function () {
  console.log("THIS WILL BE CALLED");
};
```